# Behat tests have stopped running suddenly using Selenium and Chromedriver and throws 'no such session' exception

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, behat, mink

I have Behat 3 setup on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. All my tests were running absolutely fine some days back. Scenarios get executed fine without using any browser. However, with browser-based execution, it is throwing ***'no such session'*** exception using Selenium and ChromeDriver.

I have latest Selenium Server and Chrome driver running the background. Although I know that nothing is wrong with the setup or my files since they were running fine before, still pasting them below:

composer.json

```
{
  "require-dev" : {
    "behat/behat" : "3.0.*",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver" : "*",
    "behat/mink-browserkit-driver" : "*",
    "behat/mink-extension" : "2.*",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver" : "*",
    "behat/mink" : "*"
  },
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin/"
  }
}
```

behat.yml file
`#behat.yml`

```
default:
  autoload:
    '': %paths.base%/features/bootstrap
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
      paths:
        - %paths.base%/features
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        browser_name: 'chrome'
        goutte: ~
        javascript_session: selenium2
        selenium2:
          wd_host: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
      capabilities: { "browser": "chrome", "version": "*", 'chrome': {'switches':['--start-maximized']}}
        base_url: https://axelerant.com
```

FeatureContext.php file

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;

use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver;
use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends \Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
     * context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

Error screenshot attached.[image: Error while running tests]

Comment: If you are running on localhost on default port you don't have to use the wd_host.

Comment: Comment the capabilities line and retry.

Comment: I see chrome driver 2.21, please try with 2.25

Comment: Thanks Lauda. I tried with both 2.25 and 2.23 since they have said that the bug is fixed with 2.23. But, still no luck. Getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the latest Chrome version '54' is not compatible. Downgrading to Chrome 53 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue, i have tried downloading selenium driver " selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1 " and chromedriver latest version. This solved my issue.
You can also try doing same, you may find any luck.